# page transitioning not working until after refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two pages index.html and about.html. I want a special form of transitioning between the two pages so I made this markup following a tutorial. It works but there's a problem..
Whenever I navigate to about.html, its contents are empty check but when I refreshed, the content are visible..

However, index.html stays perfect....
Please how it is possible to achieve this page transition and still keep contents and every other details intact.?
note: I run it on the server, so it's not a server issue.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(event){
  var isAnimating = false,
    newLocation = '';
    firstLoad = false;
  
  //trigger smooth transition from the actual page to the new one 
  $('#barba-wrapper').on('click', '[data-type="page-transition"]', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //detect which page has been selected
    var newPage = $(this).attr('href');
    //if the page is not already being animated - trigger animation
    if( !isAnimating ) changePage(newPage, true);
    firstLoad = true;
  });

  //detect the 'popstate' event - e.g. user clicking the back button
  $(window).on('popstate', function() {
   if( firstLoad ) {
      /*
      Safari emits a popstate event on page load - check if firstLoad is true before animating
      if it's false - the page has just been loaded 
      */
      var newPageArray = location.pathname.split('/'),
        //this is the url of the page to be loaded 
        newPage = newPageArray[newPageArray.length - 1];

      if( !isAnimating  &&  newLocation != newPage ) changePage(newPage, false);
    }
    firstLoad = true;
 });

 function changePage(url, bool) {
    isAnimating = true;
    // trigger page animation
    $('body').addClass('page-is-changing');
    $('.cd-loading-bar').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(){
     loadNewContent(url, bool);
      newLocation = url;
      $('.cd-loading-bar').off('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend');
    });
    //if browser doesn't support CSS transitions
    if( !transitionsSupported() ) {
      loadNewContent(url, bool);
      newLocation = url;
    }
 }

 function loadNewContent(url, bool) {
  url = ('' == url) ? 'index.html' : url;
   var newSection = 'cd-'+url.replace('.html', '');
   var section = $('<div class="barba-container '+newSection+'"></div>');
    
   section.load(url+' .barba-container > *', function(event){
      // load new content and replace <main> content with the new one
      $('#barba-wrapper').html(section);
      //if browser doesn't support CSS transitions - dont wait for the end of transitions
      var delay = ( transitionsSupported() ) ? 1200 : 0;
      setTimeout(function(){
        //wait for the end of the transition on the loading bar before revealing the new content
        ( section.hasClass('cd-about') ) ? $('body').addClass('cd-about') : $('body').removeClass('cd-about');
        $('body').removeClass('page-is-changing');
        $('.cd-loading-bar').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(){
          isAnimating = false;
          $('.cd-loading-bar').off('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend');
        });

        if( !transitionsSupported() ) isAnimating = false;
      }, delay);
      
      if(url!=window.location && bool){
        //add the new page to the window.history
        //if the new page was triggered by a 'popstate' event, don't add it
        window.history.pushState({path: url},'',url);
      }
  });
  }

  function transitionsSupported() {
    return $('html').hasClass('csstransitions');
  }
});
```

```css
/* -------------------------------- 

Primary style

-------------------------------- */
*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #4089a6;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

a {
  color: #283040;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 4.4rem;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Patterns - reusable parts of our design

-------------------------------- */

.cd-about  {
  background-color: #4089a6;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

#barba-wrapper Components 

-------------------------------- */
body::after, body::before {
  /* these are the 2 half blocks which cover the content once the animation is triggered */
  content: '';
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 1;
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s 0.4s;
  transition: transform 0.4s 0.4s;
}
body::before {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
body::after {
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
  -o-transform: translateY(100%);
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
body.page-is-changing::after, body.page-is-changing::before {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s 0s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s 0s;
  transition: transform 0.4s 0s;
}

#barba-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
#barba-wrapper .cd-main-content {
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
}
#barba-wrapper .cd-main-content > div {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
#barba-wrapper .cd-main-content::after, #barba-wrapper .cd-main-content::before {
  /* these are the 2 gradient overlay at the top and bottom of the .cd-#barba-wrapper-content - to indicate that you can scroll */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
#barba-wrapper .cd-main-content::before {
  top: 0;
}
#barba-wrapper .cd-main-content::after {
  bottom: 0;
}
#barba-wrapper .cd-main-content.cd-index {
  /* .cd-#barba-wrapper-content basic style - index page */
  background-color: #4089a6;
  /* vertically center its content */
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
#barba-wrapper .cd-main-content.cd-index > div {
  /* vertically center the content inside the .cd-index */
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#barba-wrapper .cd-main-content.cd-index::after {
  background-color: rgba(64, 137, 166, 0);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #4089a6, rgba(64, 137, 166, 0));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top,#4089a6, rgba(64, 137, 166, 0));
}
#barba-wrapper .cd-main-content.cd-index::before {
  background-color: rgba(64, 137, 166, 0);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4089a6, rgba(64, 137, 166, 0));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#4089a6, rgba(64, 137, 166, 0));
}
#barba-wrapper .cd-main-content.cd-about {
  /* .cd-#barba-wrapper-content basic style - about page */
  background-color: #283040;
}
#barba-wrapper .cd-main-content.cd-about > div {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
#barba-wrapper .cd-main-content.cd-about::after {
  background-color: rgba(40, 48, 64, 0);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #283040, rgba(40, 48, 64, 0));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top,#283040, rgba(40, 48, 64, 0));
}
#barba-wrapper .cd-main-content.cd-about::before {
  background-color: rgba(40, 48, 64, 0);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #283040, rgba(40, 48, 64, 0));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#283040, rgba(40, 48, 64, 0));
}
#barba-wrapper p {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 768px;
  margin: 3em auto;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #535966;
  text-align: left;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  #barba-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  #barba-wrapper .cd-main-content {
    height: calc(100vh - 40px);
  }
  #barba-wrapper.cd-index > div {
    padding-top: 200px;
  }
  #barba-wrapper.cd-index > div {
    padding-top: 50px;
  }
  #barba-wrapper p {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    line-height: 2;
  }
}

.cd-cover-layer {
  /* layer that covers the content when the animation is triggered */
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  right: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #4089a6;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, visibility 0s 0.8s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, visibility 0s 0.8s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, visibility 0s 0.8s;
}
.cd-about .cd-cover-layer {
  background-color: #283040;
}
.page-is-changing .cd-cover-layer {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-cover-layer {
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
  }
}

.cd-loading-bar {
  /* this is the loding bar - visible while switching from one page to the following one */
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 2px;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #4089a6;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.4s 0s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: visibility 0s 0.4s, -moz-transform 0.4s 0s ease-in;
  transition: visibility 0s 0.4s, transform 0.4s 0s ease-in;
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
.cd-about .cd-loading-bar {
  background-color: #283040;
}
.cd-about .cd-loading-bar::before {
  background-color: #4089a6;
}
.cd-loading-bar::before {
  /* this is the progress bar inside the loading bar */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #283040;
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  -moz-transform: scaleX(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(0);
  -o-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -ms-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}
.page-is-changing .cd-loading-bar {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) scaleX(0.3);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) scaleX(0.3);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) scaleX(0.3);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) scaleX(0.3);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) scaleX(0.3);
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.4s 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: visibility 0s 0.3s, -moz-transform 0.4s 0.4s;
  transition: visibility 0s 0.3s, transform 0.4s 0.4s;
}
.page-is-changing .cd-loading-bar::before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  -moz-transform: scaleX(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
  -o-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s 0.8s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.8s 0.8s ease-in;
  transition: transform 0.8s 0.8s ease-in;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-loading-bar {
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <!-- Resource style -->
    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
    <!-- Modernizr -->
    <title>Switch......</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <main id="barba-wrapper">
      <div class="cd-index barba-container">
        <div>
          <h1>Animated Page Transition</h1>
          <a class="cd-btn" href="about.html" data-type="page-transition"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="200px" height="1.49468in" version="1.1" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd"
viewBox="0 0 4386 1167"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <defs>
  <style type="text/css">
   <![CDATA[
    .fil0 {fill:#FFCC29}
   ]]>
  </style>
 </defs>
 <g id="Layer_x0020_1">
  <metadata id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer"/>
  <path class="fil0" d="M583 0l3219 0c321,0 584,262 584,583l0 0c0,321 -263,584 -584,584l-3219 0c-321,0 -583,-263 -583,-584l0 0c0,-321 262,-583 583,-583zm1198 262c-39,-44 -111,-74 -198,-74 -156,0 -264,112 -264,259 0,105 63,158 129,196 57,33 81,63 81,105 0,57 -48,92 -95,92 -47,0 -91,-22 -120,-56l-98 124c43,47 125,82 219,82 135,0 264,-86 264,-262 0,-111 -78,-168 -136,-203 -51,-30 -75,-51 -75,-93 0,-65 54,-96 93,-96 39,0 77,17 102,46l98 -120zm729 148l-158 0 -126 367 -2 0 -5 -367 -133 0 -136 367 -2 0 6 -367 -157 0 20 561 157 0 139 -346 1 0 7 346 163 0 226 -561zm230 0l-158 0 -97 561 158 0 97 -561zm35 -170c0,-47 -29,-81 -81,-81 -55,0 -94,49 -94,104 0,42 28,80 78,80 55,0 97,-46 97,-103zm348 170l-95 0 25 -137 -153 0 -23 137 -74 0 -22 126 74 0 -47 270c-3,17 -5,35 -5,48 0,79 47,127 141,127 27,0 61,-8 82,-18l20 -119c-10,3 -26,6 -38,6 -31,0 -46,-16 -46,-47 0,-9 2,-25 4,-37l42 -230 91 0 24 -126zm390 26c-25,-23 -61,-43 -130,-43 -169,0 -270,193 -270,373 0,124 56,222 189,222 53,0 99,-16 129,-41l-41 -124c-17,12 -34,21 -57,21 -46,0 -66,-36 -66,-96 0,-91 42,-212 112,-212 27,0 41,10 53,23l81 -123zm478 93c0,-64 -32,-136 -123,-136 -69,0 -114,43 -144,94l-2 0 59 -332 -157 0 -142 816 157 0 57 -329c11,-65 45,-110 88,-110 34,0 44,25 44,55 0,13 -2,27 -4,40l-61 344 158 0 59 -344c7,-35 11,-71 11,-98l0 0zm-3350 442c220,0 398,-178 398,-398 0,-220 -178,-398 -398,-398 -220,0 -398,178 -398,398 0,220 178,398 398,398zm-80 -387l79 -330 142 34 -80 330 -141 -34zm139 189c14,-58 -22,-115 -79,-129 -57,-14 -115,21 -129,79 -14,57 22,115 79,128 57,14 115,-21 129,-78z"/>
 </g>
</svg>
</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <div class="cd-cover-layer"></div>
    <div class="cd-loading-bar"></div>
    
    <script data-require="jquery@3.0.0" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <!-- Resource jQuery -->
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Here is A follow up work I have done on plunker. https://plnkr.co/edit/BX74GYBYHC9SNQRBceBy?p=preview

Comment: It works when I use it

Comment: Hello @Chris, thanks for your response, the problem is when I clicked on  a link to navigate to about.html, about.html loads but the content aren't visible until I refresh.

Comment: I can see the content just fine. Have you tried using a different browser like Chrome?

Comment: @Chris yes I have. I think this works because it's less complex. In my real project, I have several script controlling how things are run...give me some minute I'll be sharing that with you.

Comment: @Chris please join me  here to see it live , http://www.switch.ng/v2/index.html#&togetherjs=kir5eshcUA

Comment: @SamsonIyanda Sorry, 17 hours ago I was asleep. If you want we can join a SO chatroom. Just invite me when you are online

Comment: "@Chris I'm not sure if I can use that........here........what I found out there. "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq."